# Changing fading radius for vignette correction (OpenCV Java)

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on simple vignette correction using OpenCV (v4.1) for Java. 
The idea was to create a fading circle (from black to white) and add the value to the Brightness channel of my image. This already works, however I'd like the area/span width of the fading circle to be greater so that the transition isn't as obvious in my final image but more smooth instead
(see Snapshot below).

I created the vignette template using the `getGaussianKernel` method but I believe I cannot modify much here. I can change the `sigma` value, but that only changes the size of the circle. Is there another, more suitable method? Performance is pretty important since I have to perform this operation on many images.

Here my current approach:

```
    public void Vignette(Mat img) {

    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME ); // initializes openCV library

    Mat column = new Mat();
    Mat row = new Mat ();
    Mat product = new Mat ();
    Mat finalImage = new Mat ();
    int sigma = 240; // vignette aperture

    // creating vignette template
    column = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(img.cols(), sigma, org.opencv.core.CvType.CV_32F);
    row = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(img.rows(), sigma, org.opencv.core.CvType.CV_32F);
    Core.gemm(row,column.t(),1,new Mat(),0, product); // generalized matrix multiplication for column x row matrix

    Core.normalize(product, product, 255, 0, Core.NORM_MINMAX); // scaling values to [0...255]

    product.convertTo(product, org.opencv.core.CvType.CV_8UC3, 255); // create 3 channel matrix
    Core.bitwise_not(product, product); // invert vignette template


    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV); // convert image from BGR to HSV
    Vector <Mat> channels = new Vector(3);
    Core.split(img, channels); // split HSV channels

    Core.add(channels.get(2), product, channels.get(2)); // add value from product matrix to corresponding value of Brightness channel 

    Core.merge(channels, img); // merge HSV channels back together
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img,img,Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2BGR); // convert image back to RGB
    finalImage = img; // shows image with vignette correction
//  finalImage = product; // shows vignette template

    }
```

Snapshot (Vignette template, 'fading width' marked red):

[image: vignette template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in OpenCV, but I worked with it and I usually used Gaussian blur in cases like this. It might not be the cleanest way of doing it, but it usually gets the job done very well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply. You mean I should perform a gaussian blur on my vignette template?

Comment: Yes, that could help soften the edges, but make sure to use a big radius, since vignettes are usually really soft and sometimes even hard to notice.

Comment: Hi @mri if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.